# RTV Sealant or similar for replacement of lawnmower crankcase gasket

Tags: gasket

A while ago I hit a stump with my lawnmower and bent the crankshaft in my lawnmower.  I could only pull the bottom of the crankcase off partway, so I had to cut the crankshaft in half.  When I was doing that I accidentally scraped up the mating surfaces a bit, and of course the replacement paper gasket only works if the surfaces are perfectly smooth, and now it spits oil on either side when it runs.  My question is if I can use RTV sealant or some similar method to completely seal it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use RTV sealant, it is not suitable and you will end up at best with a leaking engine, at worst if it gets the internals, another repair job.

You can get proper gasket sealants that are oil and petrol resistant e.g [Hermatite Gasket Sealant](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hematite%20gasket%20sealant). Any decent mechanic will frown upon it's use, but for a lawn mower it should be fine. Just be sparing in it's use, if you have wodges of it oozing out from the joint, you have over-applied it.

You may still need the paper gasket in there too to maintain the correct clearances and use the gasket gunk to stop the scraped up bits leaking.